# Inserting formula into last row and autofilling until the last column Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I have

```
lastcol = Cells(14, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row
Cells(lastrow, "L").Formula = "=sum(L15:L" & lastrow - 1 & ")"
```

This sums everything from L15 to the second to last row in L
How can I adjust it such that it also autofills the formula to the right until the last column?

I've tried adjusting my code this way but it doesn't compile

```
Cells((LR & "L"), Cells(LR, lastcol - 1)).Formula = "=sum(L15:L" & LR & ")"
```

Comment: Hi Garret, what error do you get?

Comment: Hi Paul, I figured it out !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the last line to

```
 Range(Cells(lastrow, "L"), Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Formula = "=sum(L15:L" & LR - 1 & ")"
```

This sets the range to the last row in L to the last row and last column and adds the formula above, hope it helps someone out there!